# Getting wrong output in adding an image in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

My problem is that when I create or draw an image in JFrame by using

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

{}

Method I am getting a black screen instead of the image the problem code snippet is

```
ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("logo.png);
Image im=i.getImage();
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g=getGraphics();
}
```

Please suggest me an alternative method or solution to my problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should understand how Java passes values into methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider using a JPanel and overriding the paintComponent method? Something like this:

```
BufferedImage image = ... //i'll leave this blank since there are several ways to get a bufferedimage. I'll leave an eg: ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image"));
        JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }};
```

and then adding the panel to your frame. You can do the same with the container in the JFrame. The logic is simillar.

Comment: can you also please tell me that why 
setBackground() method doesn't work in JFrame?

Comment: it doesn't? how are you using it? in the JFrame you must set the background of the container and not the Frame itself.
like: frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
is this what you are asking?

Comment: But there is one problem

Comment: `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` should best be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);` since any `JComponent` **is an** `ImageObserver`..